# Edit control box can't accept error buffer

Tags: c++, arrays, string, winapi, nidaqmx

**Issue**

I'm attempting to print out an error buffer on a WINAPI GUI.  As writtin, my code attempts to read or write memory which has not been allocated causing an error to be thrown.

There must be some way to elegantly convert from a character array to a LPCTSTR. What is that way?

**Code**

```
char        errBuff[2048] = { '\0' };
```

and later

```
Error:
            if (DAQmxFailed(error))
                DAQmxGetExtendedErrorInfo(errBuff, 2048);
            if (taskHandle1 != 0) {
                /*********************************************/
                // DAQmx Stop Code
                /*********************************************/
                DAQmxStopTask(taskHandle1);
                DAQmxClearTask(taskHandle1);

            }

            if (DAQmxFailed(error)) //TODO: Test this
                printf("DAQmx Error: %s\n", errBuff);
            printf("End of program, press Enter key to quit\n");
            AppendText(hOut, L"NIDAQmx Error\n");
            wchar_t myErrBuff = (wchar_t)errBuff;
            AppendText(hOut, (LPCTSTR) myErrBuff);
            break;
```

And the contents of AppendText

```
void AppendText(HWND hEditWnd, LPCTSTR Text) {
    int idx = GetWindowTextLength(hEditWnd);
    SendMessageW(hEditWnd, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)idx, (LPARAM)idx);
    SendMessageW(hEditWnd, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)Text);
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what this line should be doing?  `wchar_t myErrBuff = (wchar_t)errBuff;`

Comment: It seems you're looking for [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar).

Comment: Why don't you define myErrBuff as wchar_t right at the beginning? Microsoft uses wchar_t as default for most of its api.

Comment: @moi `DAQmxGetExtendedErrorInfo` writes to a `char[]` - but perhaps OP could write an `AppendTextA` function instead of `AppendText(W)`

Comment: In that case - MultiByteToWideChar or look at std::format. fmtlib accepts both char and wchar for some operations.

Comment: `wchar_t myErrBuff = (wchar_t)errBuff;` is my attempting to cast the char[] to a wide character array which is what is accepted by the WINAPI text output features. For example CreateWindowW

Answer (score 1):

Since `DAQmxGetExtendedErrorInfo` writes the error message to a `char[]` I'd add a `AppendTextA` function to send those those strings directly to the WinAPI, without conversion.

```
void AppendTextA(HWND hEditWnd, LPCSTR Text) {
    int idx = GetWindowTextLength(hEditWnd);
    SendMessageA(hEditWnd, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)idx, (LPARAM)idx);
    SendMessageA(hEditWnd, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)Text);
}
```

And when the error is supposed to be sent:

```
if (DAQmxFailed(error))
    printf("DAQmx Error: %s\n", errBuff);
printf("End of program, press Enter key to quit\n");
AppendTextA(hOut, "NIDAQmx Error\n");
AppendTextA(hOut, errBuff);
```

Comment: This is assuming that the code page used by the DAQmx functions is equal to `CP_ACP` in the calling process. Which is *probably* true given NI's crappy stone age software, but is not generally a safe assumption. Unless you looked it up in the manual I suppose.

Comment: @dialer True - and I did _not_ check the documenttion for NI's software :-)

Comment: @dialer I searched the NI docs for _unicode_, _utf_, _locale_ etc but couldn't find _any_ information. Assuming `"C"`  ...

Comment: @dia It also works irrespective of the calling thread's code page in case of ASCII. Which, being stone age software, isn't all that unreasonable an assumption.

Comment: @IInspectable NI's error messages are localized iirc. But given there's no hint to UTF-8 in the documentation, just assuming it's compatible with the ANSI Win32 functions is probably the next best guess `/shrug`.

Comment: @dialer I agree that this answer is possibly taking a shortcut that may not survive in the long run. I liked your `MultiByteToWideChar` suggestion better. If you add an answer, you'd get my vote.

Comment: @ted The answer is totally fine, `MultiByteToWideChar` has the exact same issue in that you need to know the correct code page for the conversion. The sole purpose of my comment was to make future readers aware that this isn't universally applicable, especially since most modern (and sane) APIs use UTF-8 for `char` strings. Assuming it's CP_ACP is still probably the best guess for this specific DAQmx API.

Comment: @dialer Cheers! I always get a bit nervous when conversions between _something_ and _something_ else and windows code pages comes up :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for your thoughtful answer. I'm not getting results using your suggestions but am seeing that this may be an issue with code page used by NIDAQmx as described by dialer.

Comment: @MusilMark Yes, that's possible. I didn't find any information about this in the NIDAQmx doc but ... who knows :) Do you get the proper output when you do `printf("DAQmx Error: %s\n", errBuff);`? Does the printed string contain non-ASCII characters?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I set up a console allocation and no I am not able to see the output of that line but for some reason I can see the output of the following line `printf("End of program, press Enter key to quit\n")`. Thoughts?

Comment: I got it working using these lines `DAQmxGetExtendedErrorInfo(errBuff, 2048);
   printf("DAQmx Error: %s\n", errBuff);
   printf("End of program, press Enter key to quit\n");` which also prints the error buffer at the GUI

Comment: @MusilMark Ok, Does it show any non-ASCII characters in `errBuff`? You could save it to a file and check that all `char`s are 0-127 (decimal)